# Solve this using generics

Tags: ios, swift

What would be a solution to replace the following two structs `LapCGPoint` and `LapCLLocation` with a generic `Lap` struct?

Both structs do the same thing but have different types for the `locations` array and the `distanceTravelled` property. Thank you!

```
import CoreGraphics
import CoreLocation

struct LapCGPoint {

    var locations = [CGPoint]()
    var currentLocation: CGPoint? { return locations.last }
    var previousLocation: CGPoint? {
        return locations.count < 2 ? nil : locations[locations.count - 2]
    }
    var distanceTravelled: CGFloat

    mutating func add(_ location: CGPoint) {
        locations.append(location)
        if let previousLocation = previousLocation, let currentLocation = currentLocation {
            distanceTravelled += previousLocation.distanceTo(currentLocation) // distanceTo() is an extension to CGPoint
        }
    }
}

struct LapCLLocation {

    var locations = [CLLocation]()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation? { return locations.last }
    var previousLocation: CLLocation? {
        return locations.count < 2 ? nil : locations[locations.count - 2]
    }
    var distanceTravelled: Double

    mutating func add(_ location: CLLocation) {
        locations.append(location)
        if let previousLocation = previousLocation, let currentLocation = currentLocation {
            distanceTravelled += previousLocation.distance(from: currentLocation)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Btw, your `currentLocation` implementation will crash your app, sooner of later.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make `currentLocation` optional. Also, I edited my question to request a solution instead of whether it's simply possible :)

Comment: `var currentLocation: CGPoint? { return locations.last }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to do this you first need to define the requirements for the types your generic struct can work with. We can express this as a protocol:

```
protocol Point {
    associatedtype Distance: FloatingPoint
    static func distance(from: Self, to: Self) -> Distance
}
```

With this protocol we can constrain the type parameter of the generic struct. Only the operations defined in our `Point` protocol are available in the implementation of the `Lap` struct:

```
struct Lap<T: Point> {
    var locations: [T] = []
    var distanceTravelled = T.Distance(0)

    var currentLocation: T? { return locations.last }

    mutating func add(_ location: T) {
        let last = currentLocation
        locations.append(location)
        if let last = last {
            distanceTravelled += T.distance(from: last, to: location)
        }
    }
}
```

To use any type with lap struct you add an extension to it to implement the requirements of the `Point` protocol:

```
extension CLLocation: Point {
    static func distance(from: CLLocation, to: CLLocation) -> Double {
        return to.distance(from: from)
    }
}

extension CGPoint: Point {
    static func distance(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return from.distanceTo(to)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't wait to try this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

if I got your request right, you want to implement something with generics in Swift, and if that is the case, you could do something like that:

### Swift 3

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

struct Lap<T: Any> {

    var locations = [T]()
    var currentLocation: T? {
        return locations.count < 1 ? nil : locations[locations.count - 1]
    }
    var previousLocation: T? {
        return locations.count < 2 ? nil : locations[locations.count - 2]
    }
    var distanceTravelled: Double

}

extension Lap where T: CGPoint  {

    mutating func add(_ location: T) {
        self.locations.append(location)
        if let previousLocation = self.previousLocation, let currentLocation = self.currentLocation {
            self.distanceTravelled = self.distanceTravelled + previousLocation.distanceTo(currentLocation) // I don't know where the `distanceTo(...)` method is coming from...
        }
    }
}

extension Lap where T: CLLocation {

    mutating func add(_ location: T) {
        self.locations.append(location)
        if let previousLocation = self.previousLocation, let currentLocation = self.currentLocation {
            self.distanceTravelled = self.distanceTravelled + previousLocation.distance(from: currentLocation)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. distanceTo() is a CGPoint extension from SKTUtils. The above gives the following error: Value of type 'T' has no member 'distanceTo'

Comment: @metric, I think the solution is to import the necessary frameworks which contains the method which is not part of the Apple SDK, and you may need to cast `previousLocation` as `CGPoint` as well, so the error will be gone then.

Comment: the CGPoint extension is imported and working. I wonder why previousLocation and currentLocation need to be cast as CGPoint, but as CLLocation in the other Lap extension.

Comment: `self.distanceTravelled = self.distanceTravelled + Double((previousLocation as! CGPoint).distanceTo(currentLocation as! CGPoint))` seems to work. How about making `distanceTravelled` generic instead of `Double`? `distanceTravelled` needs to be a `CGFloat` in the `CGPoint` version of Lap, rather than a `Double`.

Comment: @metric, `CGFloat` is considered as a `Double` in 64bit environment and `Float` in 32 bit environment, so in your situation it is supposed not to make any difference at all.

Comment: You need to use `T == CGPoint` instead of `T: CGPoint`